# Imagemagick: Identifying when to use sampling-factor for jpeg compression

Tags: imagemagick, png, jpeg

I am automating conversion of source PNG images to JPEGs of a predefined dimension. For most the images, I don't need to provide the sampling-factor and happy with the output quality and file size. However, a few of the files get heavily distorted with artifacts. For such files, I currently manually provide the option '-sampling-factor 1x1' to get the desired output jpeg, though bigger file size.

Is there an way to identify before hand which PNG src file needs the usage of sampling-factor for conversion? That will help to pull it in the script.

Comment: Can you characterise which ones get distorted and show how they look compared to ones where there is no such problem?

Comment: If you are interested in getting JPEGs no larger than a certain size, 100k say, you could add `-define jpeg:extent=100k` into your command along with your sampling factor and let `ImageMagick` worry about the quality.

Comment: @MarkSetchell That's a good idea, I can use -sampling-factor for all and have a cutoff on file sz. Let me try that out. BTW, still just curious: aren't there any way to figure out from src png if not using sampling-factor can distort the image? I tried identify, but don't know significance of several png data.